# What is the 8-hex-digit address of the "last" byte for a PC with 32 MBytes of RAM

Tags: memory, assembly, hardware, memory-address, processor

I'm reading a book about assembly; Jones and Bartlett Publishers Introduction to 80x86 Assembly

The author give exercises but no answers to it. Obviously before going further, I want
to make sure that I fully understand the chapter concepts.

donc,

**What is the 8-hex-digit address of the "last" byte for a PC with 32 MBytes of RAM**

This is my solution:

1) convert to bits
32 MBytes = 268435456 bits

2) I subtract 8 bits to remove the last byte
268435448

3) conversion to hexadecimal
FFFFFF8

So I got **FFFFFF8**

Does this look a good answer?

Comment: Memory is addressed in bytes, not bits.

Comment: ok that mean that:

32 MBytes = 33554432 byte

minus 1 byte

33554431

convert it to hex

1FFFFFF

Doest that make more sens?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RaymondChen For assembly programming it really is. This kind of thing comes up surprisingly often when programming at this level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For assembly programming it's very helpful to be able to do simple power-of-2 calculations in your head. 1K is 2^10. So 1M is 2^20. So 32M is 2^25 (because 2^5 = 32).  So the address of the last byte is 2^25-1 (because the first byte is at 0). This is 25 bits that are all 1's (because 2^n-1 is always n 1's).  In hex, this is six F's (4 bits per F) plus an additional 1, so prepending a zero to get 8 hex digits, you have `01FFFFFF`.

Comment: Thank you, I made that mistake when I base my calculation base on bits instead on byte :S

Comment: You're welcome.  The bigger point is to learn rules of thumb about power-of-2 calculation.

Comment: The first byte is at 0 is an assumption. Although Intel processors generally use memory in this way, it's not something set in stone. And the end of the 32Mb you computer assumes the memory is contiguous, which generally is the case but again, a memory extension could be at a completely different address.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Well of course, but the question in the book that the OP quoted is about x8086 PC's. It obviously didn't intend any but the straightforward case. You should write the author.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should think about:

For most computers (all PCs) adresses are given in bytes, not in bits.

Therefore you must calculate: 32 MByte = 33554432 Bytes, minus 1 byte = 01FFFFFF (hex) as "Gene" wrote in his answer.

In reality (if you are interested in) you must also think about the fact that there is a "gap" in the address area (from 000A0000 to 000FFFFF) of real PCs so either not all the RAM is useable or the last address of the RAM comes later. This area is used for the graphics card and the BIOS ROM.

Comment: Indeed im interested in. Do you have a good book nor article link that cover that in more detail. I guess that the book Im am reading now will cover that but just in case :)

Comment: You may be interested by the Hardware Bible, although I could not see anything about the memory used by the display and the BIOS... There is a PDF copy of the previous version: http://pasargad.cse.shirazu.ac.ir/hard/HBible.pdf  Chapter 4 is all about memory.

Answer (score 0):

I thinking is : 00007FFF
because: 32MB = 32*1024 = 32768
byte last have address 32767 (7FFF)

Comment: I'm afraid it's 0x01FFFFFF. Your answer is 32 KiB.